# Windows Mobile 6.5 Icons Menu

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6

Is there an appropriate control to create an Icons Menu in Windows Mobile 6 or 6.5?

I am creating my own user control, but its hard to belive that such an important feature is missing.

This is the user control that I am developing:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Controls are part of .Net framework not OS. Which version of .Net Compact Framework you are using?

Comment: I am using cframework 3.5. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, you can use [OpenNetCF](http://opennetcf.codeplex.com/) framework which comes with a `ImageButton` control. I believe this is what you looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native menu does not support icons or graphics, it always was text only.

You may have to mimic the native menu behavior and show your app in full screen to disable the standard menu bar.